# from .. import folder1 ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python-3.7

Following some tutorial online, I am trying to import a folder as a package into a file.

Here is the hierarchy of my project:

```
folder1

folder2/
    file.py
    __init__.py
```

So, in *file.py* I am trying to import the content of *folder1* as a package:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from .. import folder1
```

But when executing file.py

```
./file.py
```

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./file.py", line 9, in
>
> from .. import folder1 ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Any solution ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution but you can run this command in your command line while in the parent directory of folder1 and folder 2:

```bash
python -m folder2.file
```

Else, you can add an `__init__.py` file in the directory containing both your folders:

```
folder1

folder2/
    file.py
    __init__.py

__init__.py
```

Last solution I can think of is:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r"/path/to/your/project")
```

You will be able to import folder1 like so:

```py
import folder1
```

Comment: I cannot use the first solution for practical reasons, I tried the 2 nd solution but it returns the exact same error

Comment: Ok, then you can try the third solution (I edited my post)

Comment: No problem ! I personally don't like it but if it works...